# How can I call a javascript function at the end of a vb.net Sub?

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

How can I call a javascript function at the end of a vb.net S

Comment: I'm not sure if you're describing the problem correctly.  Are you trying to run some JavaScript on the server side, or are you trying to push it to the client side?  If the latter, there's a disconnection between the client and the server that you're making unclear.  Basically, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to call a javascript function already written in the page after doing some VB.net.

Comment: "already written in the page"?  I think you're missing something about the lifecycle of the request and page rendering.  Has the page already been sent to the client or not?  If so, you can't interact with it.  If not, there's nothing to call on the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VB.NET subroutine is running on the server, and you want the JavaScript to run on the client, you can't.

The only way you can come close is by having your VB.NET subroutine construct some appropriate JavaScript in the page being served such that the JavaScript will run when it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) Method of the ClientScriptManager class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what I think you are, you can use `Page.RegisterStartupScript`

```
Dim Script As String = “<script language=javascript” id=’myClientScript’>myFunction();</script>”
Page.RegisterStartupScript(“callTest”,Script)
```